# WP7 talking to W7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want my WP7 device to send **keyboard commands** to Windows 7 through WiFi.
I've tried googling but I really don't know what i'm looking for, or where to start looking...

Does anyone have a tip about where to start?

Comment: This isn't really specific to programming, so it's probably more suited to superuser.com than stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you trying to develop an application that does this... or find one that already does?

Comment: Do you mean from your own code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a proxy to run on the desktop computer. It should expose a web service interface through which your phone app would control the proxy. You probably need to wrap FindWindow or similar so that you can govern which window will receive the keystrokes, and you will need to use PostMessage to inject WM_KeyUp and WM_KeyDown or whatever they are (it's been a very long time since I did this sort of thing) into the message queue for the hWnd of the target window. Then you will probably run into hassles with interprocess communication and permissions but those can be overcome.

Comment: thanks for a good answer. This could be the key to get me started.

Comment: vcsjones I'm trying to develop one.

Comment: Kev yes but I'm basically at the first step